# vim: custom highlighting for log files

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have log files that take the following form:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss SEVERITY  [thread.name] class.name:line -`

SEVERITY is one of DEBUG, INFO, WARN, or ERROR.

I have a syntax file set up that uniquely highlights the timestamp and each of the different severities.  Now, however, I want to highlight the thread name, and the class name and line number. the issue is that there may be square brackets within the log messages, so simply starting at `+\[+` and ending on `+\]+` wouldn't work.

I'd love to put down what I've tried but honestly I just have not idea how to do it.  Here's the file I have so far:

```
:syn region logTime start=+^\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}+ end=+ +me=e-1
:syn region logError start=+ERROR+ end=+ +me=e-1
:syn region logWarn start=+WARN+ end=+ +me=e-1
:syn region logInfo start=+INFO+ end=+ +me=e-1
:syn region logDebug start=+DEBUG+ end=+ +me=e-1

hi def logError ctermfg=white ctermbg=red
hi def logWarn ctermfg=yellow
hi def logInfo ctermfg=green
hi def logDebug ctermfg=blue
hi def logTime ctermfg=white ctermbg=blue
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the later chapters of [this.](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) Also, I think it would be better if you use `hi link` instead, so that color schemes would have control over your colors. For instance, `hi link logError Error`

Comment: can you explain how `hi link` works?  If I don't tell it what color to user, how would it know?

Comment: Hi link just links a syntax highlgihting group with an already existing group.  Vim has a lot of these by default, which can be listed by just entering the highlight command without any arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're overusing the `:syntax region`; for the severities, a much simpler (and faster!) `:syn keyword` is enough:

```
:syn keyword logInfo INFO
```

As the thread name comes after the severity (after whitespace), you can instruct Vim to specifically attempt to parse those afterwards:

```
:syn keyword logInfo INFO skipwhite nextgroup=logThreadName
```

To avoid that the bracketed thread name is parsed elsewhere, specify the `contained` parameter:

```
:syn match logThreadName "\[\S\+\]" contained
```

Again, a `:syn match` is simpler than a region.

Comment: Thanks!  for the class name and line number, would it be the same sort of thing? could I use `:syn match logThreadName "\[\S\+\]" contained nextgroup=logClassName` and then `:syn match logClassName " \S\+:\d\+"`?

Comment: Yes, you can chain them like that; don't forget the `skipwhite`, though!